# In a grid cell, how to share space between a button and a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I have the following XAML, where in a grid cell, I try to have a button use only the space it needs, docked to the right, and docked to the left, a textbox occupying the remainder of the space in that cell.

```
<Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto"  Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="290"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    ...

    <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4">
        <TextBox Name="txtSelectedViewUrl"  Text="{Binding Url}" IsEnabled="{Binding EditMode}"/>
        <Button Name="btnTestUrl" Content="Test" Click="btnTestUrl_Click_1" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    </DockPanel>

    ...

</Grid>
```

Instead I get the following: when initially empty, the textbox is barely visible and I can just click in it to start typing. The button is taking the whole space. As I type in the textbox, the button reduces in width leaving that space for the textbox to grow. And when you'd think the button has reached its minimal size, it does not stop there, it continues until the textbox takes the whole cell and the button becomes invisible. At least the textbox does not overflow...

I've tried various things but can't get the dock panel layout to work here. I was looking at solutions where a stack panel flowing from right to left could help, but when searching how to get the last element to fill the remainder of the space, I end up on threads advising dock panels are the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set DockPanel's `LastChildFill` property to true, and put your textbox as last child (last element inside dockpanel). That will tell `DockPanel` to display the textbox as *filling* element. Check [this post](http://wpftutorial.net/DockPanel.html) about DockPanel for reference.

```
<DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" LastChildFill="True">
    <Button Name="btnTestUrl" Content="Test" Click="btnTestUrl_Click_1" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtSelectedViewUrl"  Text="{Binding Url}" IsEnabled="{Binding EditMode}"/>
</DockPanel>
```